# Regional Settings for MS Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services

My reports are showing decimals like this 10,000,000.00, and I would like tho show like this 10.000.000,00

The Windows regional settings are OK, but I don't know from where MS Reporting Services is getting from.

Anyone knows where do I need to configure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, the settings come from the local server settings.

In each report you can customise this to pull in the browser settings. [You need to set the "Language" property to `=User!Language`](http://plataan.typepad.com/microsoftdynamics/2009/03/reporting-services-tip-about-using-the-users-regional-settings.html)

Comment: About "local server settings", how can I change it?

Comment: Same as you would in Xp or Vista: in contro panel

Comment: It's is already configured, I don't know why reporting services is not getting from there the configuration.

Comment: It'll be the locale of the service running the SSRS services then. This can be different to the machine setting. Log on with the service account, check them, try again.

Comment: The service is the local service, and it has the correct language (Portuguese). Could anyone send me a print of what setting are you talking about, just to me be sure of this? Thanks

Comment: Here is some answers http://www.ssw.com.au/Ssw/Standards/Rules/RulesToBetterSQLReportingServices.aspx#LanguageSetting

Comment: It seems that SSRS somehow knows what is regional settings on local machine requesting the report but how it knows that!?

Answer (score 1):

You could have tried using the report properties window. Select the Report object in the properties dropdown and change the Localisation language property to what you need.

This correctly changed the incoming date formats for me.

Answer (score 0):

field format: N2
and language: one of europe